# Error: param is missing or the value is empty:retweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails. I want to pass parameters to DB via controller, but I receive this error param is missing or the value is empty:retweet. I think the problem is the way of passing parameters in view.

Here is the view

```
     <% for @p in @posts %>

    <div class="panel panel-default post-panel">
      <div class="panel-body row">

        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <img src="/avatar.png" class="rounded-img" height="50px" width="50px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <p class="post-title"><a href="/user/<%= User.find(@p.user_id).username %>" class="post-owner"><%= User.find(@p.user_id).username %></a> <span class="post-creation">- <%= @p.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short) %></span></p>
          <p class="post-content"><%= @p.content %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p class="post-links">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment g-links" aria-hidden="true"></span>


            **<%= form_for Retweet.new do |f| %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag current_user.id, (:user_id) %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag @p.id, (:post_id) %>
              <%= f.submit "Retweet",   class:"btn btn-primary"%>**


            <% end %>
```

And here is the Controller

```
   def new
      @retweet = Retweet.new
   end

   def create
              @retweet = Retweet.new(post_params)
               redirect_to(:back)
     end

    private def post_params 
           params.require(:retweet).permit(:user_id, :post_id)
     end
 end
```

Comment: Just a few more comments:
In the fiew, don't name the variable `@p`. For one that would make it accessible in other views and it's also a very bad name. `post` would be a better one.
Use the `image_tag` helper method for the `avatar.png`. You'll run into trouble when you start using a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up some tutorials on basic REST controllers in Rails. Your create action didn't save the retweet.

```
def create
  @retweet = Retweet.new(post_params)
  if @retweet.save
    redirect_to(:back)
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
 end
```

Edit: Just noticed your form is all wrong:

```
  <%= form_for Retweet.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, @p.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Retweet", class:"btn btn-primary"%>**
  <% end %>
```

Mind you that you shouldn't allow settign the user_id like this, it is very easy to change it and thus mess around with your data. Instead you should add this to `retweet#create`:

```
@retweet.user = current_user
```

Comment: I still receive the same Error:                                                            Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"TDvi8Poxr3QeNsYTw2JWx13NHevm2CSTvVqzrSxA4z3ZuSnyCe/A/vaiKsCHyW9ddolR/dM8TFhi9et/deB2tQ==",
 "post_id"=>"16",
 "commit"=>"Retweet"}

Comment: Ah, yes of course. The hidden fields weren't in the retweet param. Here you go. You should read a tutorial or basic REST in rails. I updated my answer.